# xticks don't show in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to plot out a dictionary data with matplotlib in python3.6, macOS.
I want the keys of the dict to be printed as sticks but they are not showing actually.
My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
%matplotlib inline

figure(num=None, figsize=(500, 100), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

D = info_dict
x = list(D.keys())
y = list(D.values())
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), list(D.values()), rotation='vertical')
plt.margins(0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)

plt.show()
```

And the plotted one is like this:
[image]

Comment: call `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.show()`

Comment: @abhilb thanks! but it didn't work...any other idea?

Comment: what are the range of values of the valiable `D`

Comment: The ticklabels are showing fine. They are just so tiny that you easily overlook them. Reduce the figure size to something reasonable (not 500 inches!) and they will become readable.